# Login Form using Sql 3layered style

Tags: c#, sql, 3-tier

I am trying to make a decent login form for my application using Sql server management studio.
I am supposed to do it 3 layered.

I think they're both correct, in my main form i got 2 txtboxes and a button however i have no idea how to connect one and another that when i enter the username and pw they check it with the database to see if both are correct.

so far i got:

```
public class UsersDB
{
    public static Users GetUsers(string username, string password)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = QuizzesDB.GetConnection();
        Users user = new Users();

        string selectStatement =
            "SElECT * " +
            "FROM Users" +
            "WHERE User_Name = @User_Name" +
            "AND Password = @Password";
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, conn);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", username);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                user.username = reader["User_Name"].ToString();
                user.password = reader["Password"].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

The class where I get the info from my database.

the second class is

```
public class Users
{
    private string cUsername;
    private string cPassword;

    public Users() { }

    public string username
    {
        get { return cUsername; }
        set { cUsername = value; }
    }
    public string password
    {
        get { return cPassword; }
        set { cPassword = value; }
    }
}
```

i tried something like this : but i always get an error "Incorrect syntax near '='".

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;
        Users user = new Users();
        user = UsersDB.GetUsers(userName, password);
        try
        {
            user = UsersDB.GetUsers(userName, password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wrong username or password", "Login");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("login succesvol", "Login");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }           
    }
```

Comment: And your question is,...?

Comment: It would appear that your question got cut off mid sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bad coding style, you have a little problem in your SQL query:

```
string selectStatement =
        "SElECT * " +
        "FROM Users" + // <-- you need an space before "
        "WHERE User_Name = @User_Name" + // <-- also here
        "AND Password = @Password";
```

Why not use a single line query?

```
string selectStatement =
    "SElECT * FROM Users WHERE User_Name = @User_Name AND Password = @Password";
```

And if you really need multiline query, why not use [verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

```
string selectStatement =  @"
    SElECT * 
    FROM Users
    WHERE User_Name = @User_Name
    AND Password = @Password";
```